# Typescript mapped Type Guard

Tags: typescript, typeguards

i have function that can get multiple types as argumet (in my case "get" proxy handler) and that argumet should be processed diferently depends on its type.

for plain js i know how to deal with it, something like this:

```js
const calls = {
    "String": (str)=>{/*...*/},
    "Number": (num)=>{/*...*/},
    "Symbol": (symb)=>{/*...*/},
    "Object": (obj)=>{/*...*/}
}
function foo(obj){
    const name = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.name;
    if (name in calls) {
        calls[name](obj);
    } else {
    /*unknow type*/
    }
}
```

but in typescript in terms to keep type track, all that comes to mind is is type guards

```js
// isNumber, isString, isSymbol, isObject - type guards
function foo(obj: string | number | symbol):void {
    if (isString(obj)){
    /*...*/
    } else if (isNumber(obj)) {
    /*...*/
    } else if (isSymbol(obj)) {
    /*...*/
    } else if (isObject(obj)) {
    /*...*/
    } else {
    /*unknow type*/
    }
}
```

but in compare with plain js its look silly (will fast grow out of control and also make alot of unnecessary operations), so:

is there any equivalent solutions for TS?

example 2.0:

```js
class Container {
    constructor(){}
    metaData = {};
    props = new Map();
}

const valuePreProcess = {
    "Number"(target, prop, value){ return value.toString() },
    "Container"(target, prop, value){ value.metadata.parent = target; return value; }
}

const handlers = {
    set(target, prop, value){
        //define type or may be inner class of passed 'value' to process it right 
        const processedValue = valuePreProcess[<typeOfValue>](target, prop, value);
        target.props.set(prop, processedValue);
    }
}

const obj = new Proxy(new Container(),handlers);
```

probably use prototype itself as key

```js
const valuePreProcessors = new Map([
    [Number.prototype,(target, prop, value)=>value.toString()],
    [Container.prototype,(target, prop, value)=>{ value.metadata.parent = target; return value; }]
]);

const handlers = {
    set(target, prop, value){
        const processFunc = valuePreProcessors.get(Object.getPrototypeOf(value));
        target.props.set(prop, processFunc(target, prop, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.name` over `typeof obj`?  Absolutely nothing stops someone from creating a class constructor *named* `"String"` and then `foo()` would presumably mis-classify an object of that type as a `string` primitive.  It's distracting to have something prone to mistakes as part of the premise for the question.

Comment: @jcalz because of object type, if i remember corectly ```typeof <var> === 'object'``` is alweys true

Comment: But your example doesn't show anything with object types; could you show those?  Again, the *name* of a class constructor is a poor indicator of the instance type.  Nothing prevents two classes from having the same name.

Comment: collision on class constructor names also possible, but in my mind this case should be extrimly rare

Comment: With the example as written I'd be inclined to implement it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMBYQW), where you actually switch on the JS type of the object.  If you care about distinguishing object types, hopefully you'll [edit] your code example to demonstrate this so I don't have to make guesses about it

Comment: You're still not showing it, unfortunately.  Ideally you'd have something that intentionally treats two different object types differently, and actually *do* something with those values (instead of `/*...*/` which won't care about the input at all).  I understand this is a toy example but without any moving parts that matter there's nothing much to suggest.

Comment: Maybe something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6vaEw) would meet your needs?  I make a few helper functions corresponding to `typeof` checks and to `instanceof` checks and to calling in order until an appropriate one is found.  This completely avoids caring about the class constructor *name*.  Let me know if you want that written up as an answer, or if I'm still missing something about your use case

Comment: @jcalz i added example that make alot more sense, and last snippet probobly the rigth one

Comment: TS isn't great about strong typing for proxies, so I don't know if this example is the best at showing type stuff (I'd mostly just use `any` for proxies).  But [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8x5Aw) is how I'd adapt my code for that use case.  So, uh, should I write up an answer? Or am I missing something about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @jcalz first: i should point out that your examples gave me some sort if inspiration, and looks like i figured out how to solve my problem, second: you proboly should write answer looks like it must be usefull for somebodys with approximately same problem as me

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as result i used objects prototype as identifier

```js
class SomeClass {/* ... */};

type TypeOfMap = [
    typeof Number["prototype"],
    typeof String["prototype"],
    typeof Object["prototype"],
    typeof SomeClass["prototype"]
];

function getProto<T extends TypeOfMap[number]>(obj: T): T{
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
}

abstract class HandlersMap extends Map{
    abstract set<K extends TypeOfMap[number]>(key: K, value: (value: K)=>void): this
    abstract get<K extends TypeOfMap[number]>(key: K): ((value: K)=>void) | undefined;
}

const Handlers = new Map() as HandlersMap;
Handlers.set(Number.prototype,(val)=>{});
Handlers.set(Object.prototype,(val)=>{});
Handlers.set(String.prototype,(val)=>{});
Handlers.set(SomeClass.prototype,(val)=>{});

function foo(obj: TypeOfMap[number]){
    const handler = Handlers.get(getProto(obj));
    if (handler){
        handler(obj);
    } else {
        //unexpected type
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).